# pycharm not importing random-Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python

New to python, trying the guessing game. I'm using pycharm.

Heres the code followed by the error

Here is my code Code :

```
import random

lucky number= random.randrange(1,100)

guess = int(input('guess the number in the range 1-100: '))

while guess != lucky number:
    if guess < lucky number:
        print ("too low, try higher")
        guess = int(input("\n Guess a number between 1-100")
                    else:
        print ("too high, try lower")
        guess = int(input("\n Guess a number between 1-100"))

print ("you guessed the number correctly, Congratulations!")


import random

lucky number= random.randrange(1,100)

guess = int(input('guess the number in the range 1-100: '))

while guess != lucky number:
    if guess < lucky number:
        print ("too low, try higher")
        guess = int(input("\n Guess a number between 1-100")
                    else:
        print ("too high, try lower")
        guess = int(input("\n Guess a number between 1-100"))

print ("you guessed the number correctly, Congratulations!")
```

here is the error:

```
    Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "C:\Users\Shane McDonagh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Shane McDonagh/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py'
```

Comment: The title says "pycharm not importing random" but the error doesn't seem to be related to the `import random` line. What makes you think the error relates to random?

Comment: Are you able to run your code directly from a terminal rather than from within pycharm?

Comment: you need to reinstall/check  the   `python-ce` plugin, better to use pycharm professional

Comment: @TomDalton I thought it was related to import because of File "<input>", line 1, in <module>

Answer (score 0):

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Shane McDonagh/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py'

This error says that the file you are trying to run doesn't exist. It doesn't say anything about `random`. To fix the error, just right click the editor tab and select run. This should create a new run configuration for that specific file. If this doesn't fix the problem, delete all of your run configurations and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It says that the `random` library doesn't exists. This is either caused by you not installing it via `pip` or pycharm not properly setting the right configurations. Since `random` is a default library, unlike most other libraries, you do not need to install it via the `pip` command. So you must fix your configurations. O the top-right of the screen to `File > Settings > Project: project-name > Project Interpreter` and edit your configurations there, either completely remove your config and create a new one or select a different working existing one.

Also don't use the same `import` statement on a file more than once, it can cause a mountain of errors and problems, I'm assuming you pasted your code twice accidentally but I wanted to point out jsut in case.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case, I created a file inside the procject folder called random.py. I renamed it and the problem was solved

Comment: This will cause use to use a file created by you, not the random library. You will not have access to any of the functions of the library in question. Never do this.

Comment: The answer is not the solution to the question and will worsen the situation.